# how to protect your code from your client

Tags: php, encode

I have a wb application containing HTML/Javascript/PHP. I, unfortunately do not trust my client from redistributing and reselling it to other companies so i need to somehow encode my code and then give them to him. I know there are many softwares out there that does the job for PHP. Any recommendation which one to be used for better security?

Comment: This question is not constructive, since many will have their own opinion about which software to use.

Comment: This may be a case where social and legal means are better than technological ones. Put a notice in your code that you retain copyright, and sign a contract with your client that states that they may not resell or redistribute the source. If they're shifty enough that you think they'll break the contract and you won't be able to prosecute them, then what makes you think they're even going to pay you for your work?

Answer (score 4):

The only way to protect against this is to not give the client the code except for the html and javascript and only those two things interact with a api on your site. No amount of obfuscation will be enough to prevent them from getting the original code especially dynamic languages that you describe. There are a few for PHP yes, but they only protect for a short period of time.  Your best bet is to just expose an API to your client and secure the API.

Comment: After a while of thinking i believe that I do understand you fully, but how do i approach to setup an API in my case?

Comment: It really depends on your website and how it is setup to be perfectly honest and I can only give a little guidance into how to properly go about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're handing him a complete package which he can just post on a server and run, then you've handed him the complete package. No amount of encoding will prevent this client from simply making a complete copy of what you've given him and redistributing it as he sees fit. Preventing your client from doing so is the job of copyright laws - you're better off talking to a lawyer about this.

Answer (score 0):

So far I used ioncube and ZendGuard. Both are good! Its a question of choice.